# Why do "Forgotten Password?" links generally reveal usernames or registered email addresses?

Tags: obscurity, user-interface, user-names

It seems that most sites or systems will just state

> Invalid username or password

As a means to not reveal usernames for use in brute force (and other) attacks. Seems like a good idea as a general rule. 
However, many of them you can follow the *forgotten password?* link and quite often you can get

> This email address / username isn't registered

Should this not follow the same process and not reveal this information?

Is it just bad design practice that has become the norm?

Edit to add; I'm thinking about a secure system where the users aren't able to self register, nor should the general public have access. So it should be secured to those who have access and that's all.

Comment: OK, slight difference. My question is about a secure system where the general public can't register, not like Facebook et al who allow and want all and sundry on there! I'll edit to reflect this

Comment: Arguments for systems where users ARE able to self-register: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-god-login/#telltheuserwhentheiremaildoesntexist

Comment: "Invalid username or password" isn't just for security reasons. It's also because it's impossible to know for sure whether the user got the password wrong or the username.

Comment: @Ajedi32 it is very much possible, and in everything I've coded you match the username and then the password hash... Unless you're just throwing both at an api, but then the api would know which failed,the username or password.

Comment: @RemarkLima Let's say there's a user named BobA with the password `foo`, and a user named BibA with the password `bar`. BobA wants to log in, and enters his username and password, but makes a typo when entering his username and enters BibA instead of BobA. Are you going to tell him that he entered his username incorrectly, or his password?

Comment: @Ajedi32 I see your point now, quite an edge case but perfectly valid. Your original statement seemed to imply that it's not technically possible to know which one failed. Good point

Comment: @Ajedi32: in your example, the site should say "Invalid password" since the username exists. The message "Invalid username" should be shown when no username in the user database matches the entered username.

Comment: @dr01 That would be wrong though, and very misleading to the user. BobA entered his password completely correctly, it was the username he messed up on.

Comment: @Ajedi32: the user is much more likely to misspell his password than his username, which most of the time is the same on all sites. I see your point, but it's such an edge case that it's not worth considering in practice.

Comment: @user11153: The linked article's main point seems to be that it can be problematic to remember "which of my 10 email addresses did I use to sign up here?"  I respectfully submit that that's simply a symptom of a bigger problem: why in the *world* do you have 10 email addresses?!?  I have 3: my personal email, my work email, and a Gmail account I got back in the early beta days because a friend worked for Google, which I never use.  I find it difficult to imagine why anyone would need or want 10.

Comment: @dr01 I disagree. The whole point of telling the user explicitly when he has entered a username that doesn't exist in the database is to cover the case where the user doesn't remember his username, correct? In any other case, "invalid  username or password" wouldn't be a UX problem, since the user would know he entered his username correctly (and therefore it must be the password he got wrong). So if we assume the user _doesn't_ remember his username, then implying that the user has entered his username correctly when in fact he hasn't would be a bad idea.

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/13523/22773

Comment: @MasonWheeler For example, I use ONE gmail e-mail, but I always use `name+some.site.alias@gmail.com`, so theoretically I have infinity number of e-mail addresses. Same situation could be with someone with e-mail in custom domain and `catch-all` enabled.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I (like I'm sure many people here) have my own domain.  I can easily create aliases for registering an account. (For that matter I still have some accounts on my ISP-provided address, my gmail, my work address, my previous work address... And that's assuming the username is an email address, not your 4th choice of handle after 3 "That name is already taken" messages.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, it is bad security practice indeed.

When using the Forgotten Password feature, the site should respond with a message: *"An email has just been sent to the specified email address, if it exists and is registered within our system. Please read the email and follow the instructions."*

Or simply: *"Please check your email inbox for instructions on how to proceed to reset your password"*, since it's a safe assumption that the account reset procedure was initiated by the legitimate account owner.

EDIT: It has been pointed out that an attacker might find out whether an email address is registered in the system by trying to open an account with that address. To thwart this attack, the registration procedure must be changed too; the user should be allowed to register only after he/she verified his/her email address, as follows.

Upon entering an email address for a new registration, the site should respond with the message *"An email has been sent to the email address you provided. Please read the email and follow the instructions to complete the registration, if necessary".*  Then the email message would contain the steps to follow to complete the registration, or a simple warning to the user if the email address was already registered.

Comment: I prefer the first, since most times I use this feature is not just because I can't remember my password, but I'm not 100% sure I even have an account - The first message subtly reminds you that if its not received you don't have an account, whereas the second sort of implies that the account exists and the email was sent.

Comment: Thanks. Now, how about if there's a set of questions and answers to reset the password, no email involved? Do you still take them through the process on the basis that they think it's all valid? In the context that anyone trying this absolutely will have an account

Comment: +1: I agree with this answer, however I should point out that it is often possible to determine the same/similar info by attempting to create a new account, and having the process fail or succeed.

Comment: I think the safest way to do this is to bring the user towards the whole process of answering all questions and only at the end tell him/her if the procedure was successful. However, this approach 1) is not exactly user-friendly and 2) will introduce a security hole in your system if the answers, from the point of view of an attacker, are easier to guess than the password.

Comment: @Numeron: good point, edited my answer to take this into account.

Comment: This is an interesting and original solution to the implicit leak of information revealed by probing sign-up forms (like "that username is taken, try another!" with AJAX). I don't think I've ever seen this implemented though so early in the process. I've proposed adding email verification "walls" to sign-up processes in the past (usually a final activation step) but clients have always rejected the concept due to the additional friction to the customer-acquisition pipeline.

Answer (score 16):

There's a reason few websites follow that "security" measure: you lose usability (and users) without gaining *any* security.

Any website with even the smallest hint of security will enforce a **limit** on the amount of times you can "guess" a password OR a username, to prevent people iterating over all of the existing usernames. This limit needs to be imposed on all facets; registration, login, and password recovery.

You may be asking: "If it's so bad to give a generic error message, why do people do it?". The answer comes from the distant past, when security was young and underdeveloped. Authentication was often done offline or on a local network, which allowed attackers to brute force as fast as their processor would allow. With an unlimited number of guesses happening at a rapid pace, it was trivial to iterate over every username in existence, if the system reported that a username existed or not.

Bigger companies (Facebook, for instance) tend to have UI/UX divisions who run usability tests, showing just how many users are lost due to anti-usability security theater. But many smaller companies don't have UI/UX resources, and end up following "best practices" like this, and even stupider things like "[security images](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19155/effectiveness-of-security-images)".

Related reading: [Disclose to user if account exists?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40694/disclose-to-user-if-account-exists/40695#40695)

Answer (score 2):

As @Ahueahuehauehua said, @dr01 answer is not user experience friendly in my opinion too.

`Always remember that security through obscurity IS NOT a valid approach.`

`Invalid username or password` simply says that username and password doesn't match, I mean, either username or password (or both) are incorrect.
So, in any case, just show a message like `Invalid username or password`, not because of security (which is not secure at all), but because username or password or both of them, are incorrect.

The best way is to increase signin security, by best practices, and not by obscurity. Try limiting signin/signup/forgotten password re-tries. For example, limit them to 5 tries/IP/hour and also 5 tries/username/hours. Also, set a maximum tries for 24 hours (for example, 10 tries/IP/24 hours and 10 tries/username/24 hours).
So, nobody can guess more that 3650 password in a year for each username.

I just want to say it again that `security through obscurity is not a valid approach.`

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues here which need to be considered and some too often
quoted misleading statement of security through obscurity.

To address the security through obscurity statements. Making something obscure does
not automatically imply security through obscurity. The notion of security through
obscurity refers to the practice of relying solely on the obscurity for the
security. It is perfectly acceptable and in some cases even good practice to
incorporate obscurity into a security control.

As an example of the differences. Consider telnet, which is inherently insecure
because it sends passwords in plain text. Moving the telnet service from its standard
port to some other port and believing this has addressed the security issue is
security through obscurity. It has not addressed the underlying problem of plain text
passwords being transmitted and relies on nobody sniffing traffic destined to that
non-standard port to maintain security.

On the other hand, you might decide to move your ssh service to a non-standard
port. This decision might be because you have a system which only you log into and
you have noticed lots of attempts to brute force access via ssh. Moving this service
to another non-standard port will reduce the number of brute force attempts against
your ssh service. As you are the only one using it, it doesn't represent significant
inconvenience and while it has made that service more obscure, it isn't classified as
security through obscurity because moving it to another port is not the sole security
protection. You have reduced your threat exposure, but you are still using all the
other standard good practice you would have for an ssh service.

Obscurity in security is a common control and perfectly acceptable provided it is not
the only control you are relying on.

With respect to the original question as to indicating whether email or username is
valid when performing a recover password operation is a good idea, it really depends
on a lot of other factors. Security controls need to be evaluated within the context
they are being applied to. We have general 'best practice' guidelines, but these are
just that, guidelines, not rules. In general, we do not want to provide information
to attackers which they can use to assist them in their attack. However, we also need
to consider the value of the resource we are protecting.

For example, I use a RSS feed reader service. For me, this is a low risk
application. There is not a lot of value there for an attacker. If I forget my
password and try to use the forgotten password feature and it just tells me it failed
rather than telling me I had the wrong email address, then it will likely be more
frustrating than necessary. It could be I had a typo in the address I entered and
being told the address was wrong would really help. I know then that the problem is
with what I entered. Telling me something too generic prevents me from trying to
diagnose what was wrong - was it something wrong I entered, is it a problem with
their server, what?

On the other hand, I probably don't want my bank using a forgotten password feature
which will give additional information, such as my account name to an attacker. In
this case, perhaps a message stating that the forgotten password functionality has
failed and asking me to contact phone support would be more appropriate. If on the
other hand, the problem is with my gmail account, I'm probably not that concerned
because it is trivial to determine valid and invalid email addresses just using basic
SMTP commands to the server.

The basic point is, you need to balance user experience and security. You need to
understand what the threat vectors are and what the appropriate controls are for the
resource being protected. There is no always should be this or that - it all comes
down to the context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is bad practice, exactly for the reasons you state.

When I write this kind of thing, I give a generic message along the lines of *"An email has been sent to this address"* regardless of whether the account existed or not.

There is a mitigating factor, however, in that a hacker trying to use a form like this find out what addresses are registered will trigger emails to be sent to users whose addresses he finds. This could serve as a warning to the user. Indeed, some sites include warning messages in their emails for users to beware of a potential attack if they didn't request the reset.

This could be sufficient to dissuade hackers from trying to use the reset form to harvest addresses.